# Problema con listas por comprensión en Python usando if

Tags: python

Si hago esto funciona perfectamente el filtrado de la lista:

```
I = [1,2,3]
d = {1:20, 2:21, 3:22}

print([i for i in I if d[i]>20])
```

Resultado: [2,3]

En cambio si hago esto no funciona y genera un error:

```
I = [1,2]
P = [1,2,3]
dd = {(1,1):20, (1,2):21, (1,3):22}

print([(i,p) for i in I for p in P if dd[i,p]>20])
```

Resultado: KeyError (2,1)

¿Alguien podría decirme cómo resolverlo?

Comment: Hola Jaime, bienvenido a [es.so]. No tienes claves de la forma `(2, x)` en tu ejemplo, para tu diccionario debe ser `I = [1]` no `I = [1, 2]`. ¿Es solo un error tipográfico o existe alguna razón para generar índices de la forma (2, x) para ese ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Jaime:

Esto sucede porque al llegar al segundo objeto de la lista I no consigue como key el valor (2,1) en el diccionario dd.

Una forma de solucionarlo es colocar una condición que verifique antes si esa key existe para el diccionario:

```
for i in I:
    for p in P:
        if (i,p) in dd > and dd[(i,p)] > 20:
            print(i,p)
```

En tu caso, que el resultado lo imprimes en una lista sería:

```
print([(i,p) for i in I for p in P if (i,p) in dd and dd[i,p]>20])
```

Comment: Efectivamente, ya había llegado a la misma conclusión que tú. Con los bucles separados sabía que lo podía resolver, pero lo quería más compacto. Poniendo el if (i,p) in dd and dd[i,p]>20 funciona perfectamente. Gracias Adrián por responder.

Comment: De nada Jaime. Si crees que la respuesta te ha servido de ayuda para la pregunta podrías marcarla como válida. Saludos.